# Optimising a slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

[image]

I have a MySQL query as follows:

```
SELECT KeywordText, SUM(Frequency) AS Frequency FROM Keyword, Keyword_Polling_Frequency_Index
WHERE Keyword.KeywordText 
IN ('deal', 'obama' and other keywords...) 
AND RSSFeedNo IN (106, 107 and other RSS feeds) 
AND PollingDateTime 
BETWEEN '2011-10-28 13:00:00' AND '2011-10-28 13:59:00' 
AND Keyword.KeywordNo = Keyword_Polling_Frequency_Index.KeywordNo 
GROUP BY Keyword.KeywordText 
ORDER BY Keyword.KeywordText ASC
```

The query is used by an hourly batch program which involves two tables and is meant to get the frequencies of a list of keywords from a list of RSS feeds for a given hour. The Keyword_Polling_Frequency_Index table has a composite primary key of KeywordNo, RSSFeedNo and PollingDateTime. The query joins this table to the Keyword table which contains the KeywordText. column keywordText has a MySQL MyISAM full text index.

In testing this was found to perform satisfactorily but has now started running very slowly and affects the interactive speed of pages of the application. When I check the MySQL logs, I find that MySQL is creating temporary tables.

So, my question is, given that this query has to handle dozens of keywords in dozens of RSS feeds to calculate the frequencies, can anyone suggest an optimisation?

I have thought of breaking the query up by keyword but am not convinced of the practicality of this.

Can anyone help?

I am using MySQL Community Edition 5.X and an EXTENDED EXPLAIN of a version of this query is shown above.

SQL for the tables is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `keyword` (
`KeywordNo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`KeywordText` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`UserOriginated` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL,
`Active` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL,
`UserNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`StopWord` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL,
`CreatedDate` date NOT NULL,
`CreatedTime` time NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`KeywordNo`),
FULLTEXT KEY `KEYWORDTEXT` (`KeywordText`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=44047 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


CREATE TABLE `keyword_polling_frequency_index` (
`KeywordNo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`RSSFeedNo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`PollingDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`Frequency` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Active` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL,
`UserNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`KeywordNo`,`RSSFeedNo`,`PollingDateTime`),
KEY `FK_keyword_polling_frequency_index_1` (`UserNo`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_keyword_polling_frequency_index_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserNo`) REFERENCES `user`    (`UserNo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to create a composite index for `(KeywordNo, PollingDateTime)` (order matters)

Comment: Also you may try to create a simple index for `KeywordText`, because fulltext index in this case is not usable.

Comment: The keys of the index table are meant to allow for keyword x in feed y during hour z. I can change the index on Keyword.KeywordText but in what way is fulltext 'not usable'?

Comment: In order to use fulltext index you should use `MATCH... AGAINST` clause. By the way, you can have several different indexes for the same column if you need them in other queries.

Comment: I understand RSS feed numbers and keyword are in no way related and that relationship is derived from the two INs in your query. If you use a third table to index those two, you can make better use of resources as you'll be able to directly link to INDEXes or PKs. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Good point. That's one thing I've overlooked. But a few other queries use the fulltest index with MATCH. But they can be refactored.

Comment: @Leon: The table is an index of the frequencies of the actual keywords as previously found in RSS feeds per hour. At the time of the query running, it is trying to find the frequencies of the keyords per hour, per feed in the IN lists. But when the query runs, the two lists are essentially unrelated.

Comment: ok, so let's drop the keyword text from the IN - instead of doing that, I suggest first generating a list of the `KeywordNo`s you are seeking. this way you'll first match them against the `keyword` table  and reduce the number of records to compare (INs are N x N comparisons). probably using EXISTS will improve over the IN usage

Comment: @Leon: I can certainly remove the Keyword table from the query which will remove the join. But are you suggesting that the query becomes something like: WHERE KeywordNo EXISTS (1, 2...)  
and RSSFeedNo EXISTS (106, 107...)  
AND PollingDateTime  
BETWEEN '2011-10-28 13:00:00' AND '2011-10-28 13:59:00'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned previously, add an index to the PollingDateTime field in the order mentioned as well. This is my suggestion:

```
SELECT 
    K.KeywordText, 
    SUM(F.Frequency) AS Frequency 
FROM 
    Keyword K, Keyword_Polling_Frequency_Index F
WHERE 
    EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Keyword K1
        WHERE
            MATCH K1.KeywordText AGAINST ('deal obama "another keyword" yetanother' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            AND K1.KeywordNo = K.KeywordNo
        )
    AND K.KeywordNo = F.KeywordNo
    AND F.PollingDateTime BETWEEN '2011-10-28 13:00:00' AND '2011-10-28 13:59:00'
    AND F.RSSFeedNo IN (106, 107, 110)
    GROUP BY K.KeywordText 
    ORDER BY K.KeywordText ASC
```

This will probably reduce the number of records for the comparison (SQL inside-out parsing) instead of directly matching two tables (N x N).

Comment: I will try this in the next few days and let you know. Also, the PollingDatetime will be placed first in the primary key order.

Comment: I'm going to try a quick and dirty run now.

Comment: poorly quicker or quick enough?

Comment: That will depend upon code database changes and code changes. At the moment the query executes multiple times per batch run; each query execution is for a different set of keywords with a different set of feeds. So I'm thinking of changing this so that I get all keywords and feeds in one go, and then execute the query once. The results can be written to memory of temporary file and each collection of keywords and feeds can then read this structure. That should speed things up a lot. But it already looks like your query is noticeably faster than mine during a single execution. I'm grateful.

Comment: What took 45 mins last weekend has just been timed at 51 seconds. thanks to the respondents.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any indexes you should create relevant indexes.

The minimum index is on `keyword_polling_frequency_index.PollingDateTime`

Comment: I believe that MySQL creates indexes for primary keys automatically. Certainly, the keys I have in the index table have an index of type PRIMARY.

Comment: @MrMorgan Yeah, but the problem is that `PollingDateTime` is at the last position in PRIMARY index. This is not suitable for this particular query.